# Displaying author for each chapter in book

Tags: chapters

I am preparing a book in which each chapter is contributed by different people.I want to include their name after the chapter title.How to I do it.If I use `\maketitle` it is useing the title and author name for the **book**. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\author{S.Subham Soni}
%\title{A Sample Test} --> I don't want to use this
\begin{document}
%\maketitle
\chapter{This is a test}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Though in another forum but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501680/how-should-i-add-an-author-subtitle-under-a-chapter-title) contains the exact solution to your problem.

Comment: Should the authors be also included in an eventual ToC?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Why don't define a new command `\chapterauthor`

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\chapterauthor}[1]{%
  {\parindent0pt\vspace*{-25pt}%
  \linespread{1.1}\large\scshape#1%
  \par\nobreak\vspace*{35pt}}
  \@afterheading%
}
\makeatother
```

and use it in this way?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\chapterauthor}[1]{%
  {\parindent0pt\vspace*{-25pt}%
  \linespread{1.1}\large\scshape#1%
  \par\nobreak\vspace*{35pt}}
  \@afterheading%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is a test}
\chapterauthor{S.Subham Soni}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### EDIT

Just in case you want to add authors' info in the ToC, here is a different version.

Use the starred version of `\chapterauthor` (`\chapterauthor*`) in correspondence of starred chapters (`\chapter*`).

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{suffix}

\newcommand\chapterauthor[1]{\authortoc{#1}\printchapterauthor{#1}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\chapterauthor*[1]{\printchapterauthor{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printchapterauthor}[1]{%
  {\parindent0pt\vspace*{-25pt}%
  \linespread{1.1}\large\scshape#1%
  \par\nobreak\vspace*{35pt}}
  \@afterheading%
}
\newcommand{\authortoc}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip-10pt}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\contentsline{chapter}%
    {\hskip1.3em\mdseries\scshape\protect\scriptsize#1}{}{}}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip5pt}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{1st chapter}
\chapterauthor{K.DINESH KUMAR \\ II Year B.Tech CSE}
\lipsum[1]

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{2nd chapter}
\chapterauthor{S.Subham Soni}
\lipsum[1]

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter*{3rd chapter}
\chapterauthor*{Unknown}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Output (ToC):

[image]

Comment: You may wan to make it more advanced such that ht author can also be added to the TOC

Comment: \chapterauthor{K.DINESH KUMAR \par II Year B.Tech CSE} when I use this , I want enough spacing, How do I that?

Comment: @subhamsoni I've edited the answer, change the value of `\linespread` if you want more spacing. Note that now you can use either `\par` or ``\\`` inside `\chapterauthor`

Comment: Thank you for this! I'd like the author names in the Table of Contents page to be of bigger font. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @Arundhathi In the definition of `\authortoc` change `\scriptsize` to `\large`, for example.

Comment: That's a really nice code @karlkoeller ! 
Is it possible though to make the author name not fully capital letter ?

Comment: sorry, i finally found it: the environment \??shape allows to define the shape of your letters, so "sc" for small capitals. 
I replaced it with "up" (for upright) and it worked : \upshape#1

Comment: Is there an quick fix to prevent page breaks in the ToC between the chapter title and the authors?

Comment: By using `\hskip1.3em` in `authortoc`, the author name is not properly aligning with the chapter title. So, I have put  `\hskip1.5em` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Not a solution, but idea on how to proceed

```
\author{....}
\title{...}
\makechaptertitle
\label{chap:key}
```

to start a chapter. Then `\makechapter` title could call `\chapter` and whatever else you need.

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but I'm not sure to understand how it works. I'm thinking in a chapter with own author and show also the institution and the e-mail, so could I use your idea for that and how?