# How to put a name under a section caption

Tags: captions

I am the author of one section of a report. I want to but my name right under the caption of this section. And I want this to appear in the table of contents.

[This Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156862/displaying-author-for-each-chapter-in-book) gives a very nice answer to this question, if I wanted to but my name under a chapter's caption. However, it is not the chapter that I am writing, but only this one section. For some reason the code provided in the mentioned question doesn't work for sections, and I don't understand LaTeX very well, such that I could change it. Maybe someone can help?

Here is the code that I have copied and tried out:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{suffix}

  \newcommand{\printsectionauthor}[1]{%
      {\parindent0pt\vspace*{-25pt}%
      \linespread{1.1}\large\scshape#1%
      \par\nobreak\vspace*{35pt}}
      \@afterheading%
    }
    \newcommand{\authortoc}[1]{%
      \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip-10pt}%
      \addtocontents{toc}{%
        \protect\contentsline{section}%
        {\hskip1.3em\mdseries\scshape\protect\scriptsize#1}{}{}}
      \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip5pt}%
    }

\title{Title of the Report}
\author{My Name}

\maketitlepage
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter of the Report}
\Section{My Section}\label{mySection}
\printsectionauthor{My Name}
\Subsection{First Subsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of posting code fragments, can you please put the fragments into a compilable document that that people can play with.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please always post a full minimal example of how your code is used. In many cases the document class you are using greatly affect the chosen solution. As for adding to the toc in a section related form (per the second macro) give one guess as to how you'd change thst from being chapter related to being section related.

Comment: ok. I have tried to create this example. As on how I would change it? To me the command only seems to handle vertical spaces and similar, meaning where to put the name. I don't see how it is specific to chapters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`article` class does not provide `\chapter`, `\Section` and `\Subsection`. So I will use `report` class with `\chapter`, `\section` and `\subsection`.

You could load package `tocbasic` and declare a new ToC entry for the sectionauthor.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocbasic}

\makeatletter
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level=1,
  indent=3.8em,
  numwidth=0pt,
  entryformat=\normalfont\scshape\scriptsize,
  pagenumberformat=\@gobble,
  linefill=\hfill,
  onstartsamelevel=\relax
]{tocline}{sectionauthor}

\newcommand{\printsectionauthor}[1]{%
  {\parindent0pt\vspace*{-10pt}%
  \large\scshape#1%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{sectionauthor}{#1}%
  \par\nobreak\vspace*{10pt}
  }%
  \@afterheading%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter of the Report}
\section{My Section}\label{mySection}
\printsectionauthor{My Name}
\subsection{First Subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! It is working! ...now I only need to understand what is actually going on, hahaha

Answer (score 1):

Your code produces a large amount of errors and I am not sure what the purpose of various parts is. So I just followed your link, copied the definition of `\chapterauthor` to `\sectionauthor` and made marginal changes.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\chapterauthor}[1]{%
  {\parindent0pt\vspace*{-25pt}%
  \linespread{1.1}\large\scshape#1%
  \par\nobreak\vspace*{35pt}}
  \@afterheading%
}
\newcommand{\sectionauthor}[1]{%
  {\parindent0pt\vspace*{-15pt}%
  \linespread{1.1}\large\scshape#1%
  \par\nobreak\vspace*{15pt}}
  \@afterheading%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is a test}
\chapterauthor{S.~Subham Soni}

\section{The content of this section is not valid on Tuesdays
}
\sectionauthor{M.~Murmeltier}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an entirely different approach.  Since we want the TOC dotted line to connect to the title and not the author, the author is horizontally overlapped with the title, only on the next line.  It is treated like a very large descender.  Note: this only works for a one line title.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{suffix}

\title{Title of the Report}
\author{My Name}

\begin{document}
\titlepage
\tableofcontents
%\cleardoublepage
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
%\listoffigures% not relevant

\chapter{First Chapter of the Report}
\section{\rlap{\normalsize\raisebox{-\baselineskip}{My Name}}My Section}\label{mySection}
\subsection{First Subsection}
\end{document}
```