# Displaying chapter authors in headers

Tags: header-footer, chapters, author

I'm editing a book written by different authors, each chapter one or several authors. I would like to include the name of the authors of each chapter in the ToC, and **also in the headers**.

The answer from [karlkoeller](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/27635/karlkoeller) to the question [Displaying author for each chapter in book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156862/displaying-author-for-each-chapter-in-book?newreg=cc7bd951630649d0af0686b5a3446973) explain a method to include the authors in the ToC. I would like to modify this method a little bit in order to be able to print them in the headers.

Here is my Minimal NotWorking Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,portuges]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[paperwidth=17cm,paperheight=24cm]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\thechapterauthor[1]{}
\newcommand\chapterauthor[1]{\authortoc{#1}\printchapterauthor{#1}}
\newcommand{\printchapterauthor}[1]{%
  {\parindent0pt\vspace*{-25pt}%
  \linespread{1.1}\large\scshape#1%
  \par\nobreak\vspace*{35pt}}
  \@afterheading}
\newcommand{\authortoc}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip-10pt}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\contentsline{chapter}%
    {\hskip1.3em\mdseries\scshape\protect\scriptsize#1}{}{}}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip5pt}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textbf{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\thechapterauthor}
\makeatother   

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\title{Título}
\author{Autor}
\maketitle
  \section*{Limiar}
    \lipsum[2-4]
\tableofcontents{}

\mainmatter
  \chapter{Chapter 1}
    \chapterauthor{Zê Povinho}
     \lipsum[1]
  \section{Section 1}
    \lipsum[1-8]
   \section{Section 2}
     \lipsum[3-7]
  \chapter{Chapter 2}
    \chapterauthor{L. Nemsei, P. Quemsabe}
     \lipsum[3-4]
  \section{Section 3}
     \lipsum[2-5]
  \subsection{Subsection 1}
     \lipsum[5-8]
\end{document}
```

Pdflatex does not print any warnings or errors, but the name of the authors does not appear in the headers. What to do?

Comment: Don't show only some snippets, create a small, complete example that demonstrates the problem. That makes it much easier to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sufficient to make `\chapterauthor` to define `\thechapterauthor`:

```
\newcommand\thechapterauthor{} % initialize
\newcommand\chapterauthor[1]{%
  \authortoc{#1}\printchapterauthor{#1}%
  \renewcommand\thechapterauthor{#1}%
}
```

[image]